# browser extension - remove all browser history for a particular website when tab is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

Is possible in a browser extension to remove the history of a particular website when a tab or the browser is closed? I've read the chrome history api documentations but it seems that is possible only to remove a single url from the history but not all the pages visited related to a domain. Is there a solition for this?

Comment: You'll have to use search() then remove the found urls.

Comment: I've tried today with the `search()` method but it will not find all the entries that are in the history, I've done a test with five visited pages of a website, the same website was visited in the past days, the serach will return only the five pages visited recently, not all the history related to that website

Comment: See the documentation, by default it only searches 24 hours, so you need to specify a limit explicitly.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help